# A code for AddHandler VB.Net/C#

Tags: vb.net

I create comboBox control at dynamically and add items in it as shown bellow:

```
Dim comboTime As New ComboBox
Me.Panel1.Controles.Add(comboTime)
comboTime.Items.Add("Hour")
comboTime.Items.Add("Week")
comboTime.Items.Add("Day")
comboTime.Items.Add("Month")
comboTime.Items.Add("Year")
comboTime.SelectedIndex = 2
AddHandler comboTime.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf comboTime_selectedindexchanged
```

By default, "Day" is selected by the program (index 2). I would like to add a message alerting a user if s/he selects index 0 (Hour).  Maybe some statement of code is needed for the AddHandler comboTime but I do not know how to do that. Does anyone have an idea how to do that? For instance, if "Hour" is selected, a messagebox pops up and say "this is Hour"

My question is not how to add a message box. But How can separately get the AddHandler outside of this code.

Comment: Just use `comboTime_selectedindexchanged` to provide the code that contains the `MessageBox.Show` if the `SelectedIndex` is 0.

Comment: I tried sub comboTime_selectedindexchanged() ... end sub but cannot see anything

Comment: oh, there is one line Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(comboTime)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution which is no different than the others outside of complete example and slightly better way to initialize the control where it's up to you for how to handle when the user selects day. Feel free to name the control if you need to reference it later in your code.

If an item is not located with day the index will be -1

This code would be placed into Form load or Form Shown events

```
Dim cbo As New ComboBox

cbo.DataSource = New String() {"Hour", "Week", "Day", "Month", "Year"}
cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
cbo.Location = New Point(25, 40)
Me.Controls.Add(cbo)
cbo.SelectedIndex = cbo.FindString("day")
AddHandler cbo.SelectedIndexChanged,
    Sub(s As Object, ea As EventArgs)
        If CType(s, ComboBox).Text.ToLower = "hour" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Here")
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above is valid for Framework 3.5 or better while prior to this we would do the following

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cbo As New ComboBox

    cbo.DataSource = New String() {"Hour", "Week", "Day", "Month", "Year"}
    cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    cbo.Location = New Point(25, 40)
    Me.Controls.Add(cbo)
    cbo.SelectedIndex = cbo.FindString("day")
    AddHandler cbo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf IndexChanged
End Sub
Private Sub IndexChanged(s As Object, ea As EventArgs)
    If CType(s, ComboBox).Text.ToLower = "hour" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Here")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how do you call that from Form_Load for instance? I tried but it doesn't recogniz the Sub section

Comment: The sub portion is for Framework 3.5 or higher which creates a anonymous event. I added a secondary example for older Frameworks and will work in current Frameworks also.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with:

```
If comboTime.Text = "Hour" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Hour selected", "Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End If
```

For more information on MessageBox see [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show-vbnet)

Comment: where do you put that statement? Since the default index is to, on form load it pops up the message box. I just need to pop up only when the user selects item in the comboTime and if that selection is "Hour"

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have been clearer on that, since you only want the message box to appear when the `comboTime` is changed just add it to the end of that method.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to eliminate the popping-up of message boxes you could simply display the selected item in a textbox or label, this makes the form more user friendly and easier to work with.

Add a label to your userform and name it "lblCombo1" then

Add the following code inside the class:

```
    Private Sub comboTime_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comboTime.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblCombo1.Text = cmboTime.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Has errors. Can you check it? it says cmboTime requires WithEvent variable and declaration

Comment: @codelearner You should be able to spot that "cmboTime" could easily be a typo for "comboTime".

Comment: @luke, I did notice that but still errors are showing like comboT_me_SelectedIndexChanged has appeared several times and a warning that WithEvent variable is required.  I liked the approach but couldn't get it working

Comment: Sorry about that it was a typo thanks for noticing. I'm too used to my own syntax :) * Post Edited

Comment: Delete the code, add the label to your form then double click it to enter the code window and to ensure the procedure is handling the correct object. Simply add the line of code "lblCombo1.text = cmboTime.Text". If there are any errors from there, please let me know what the error is.                           Note: Make sure that event is "SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: My problem is that I do not have 'SelectedIndexChanged' at design time.  The comboTime is created at runtime. I cannot access the handler at design time to add the code lblCombo1.Text=...

Comment: Ok, I removed the 'Handles comboTime.SelectedIndexChanged' section and passed the lblCombo1.Text value from Me.Palel1.Controls(0).Text, then used the if statement to filter the 'Hour' and show a message. It did work

Comment: Good, glad we got there :-)